# select one element from the RDD pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new in spark and I want to select one element from the RDD. I use the following code:

`(c2.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (key,index) : index == 1)).collect()`

but I get this error :  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Could you please let me know what can be the problem

Comment: Method "rdd.first" can be used (at least in Scala)

Comment: I think rdd.first returns the first element but I want to get the element specified by the index x

Comment: Did you try`collect()[indexno]`

Comment: thank you. collect()[indexno] worked well